# passing data to popup( SkinnablePopUp ) from a view the creates it

Tags: apache-flex, popup

I,m opening a popup in my mobile project and I need to pass the opened popup some data ?
Is this possible if so how ?

Comment: Generically; after you create the popup; just pass variables into it `myPopUp.myCustomInstanceVariable = myValue`; no different than creating any other component in ActionScript.

Comment: Can you explain how to add "myCustomInstanceVariable" to the popup. I have created a custom popup using SkinnablePopUpContainer

Comment: Create a custom component that extends SkinnablePopUpContainer and add a variable `public var myCustomInstanceVariable : DataType`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it,

1. As mentioned by Reboog, myPopup.someProperty = value.
2. After the popup is launched, dispatch an application wide event with data in it for the popup to handle the event and display(Custom Event that you have to create, embed data and dispatch it)
3. Store the data in a Model location i.e., either a singleton, from the popup, you can access it by Singleton.getinstance().value.

Comment: I don't understand your #2 suggestion.

Comment: As soon as you instantiate the popup listen for event X. Dispatch a global event X from a different part of the application which needs to send data to the popup. then read the data from the event on the popup.(this solution helps passing data to the popup at the later point, not immediately after the popup creation)

Comment: I don't understand which component is doing the listening and which component is doing the dispatching in this scenario.  A bubbling event should go up the display hierarchy to the stage; but I thought the popup--displayed with the PopUpManager existed outside of the display hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, the bubbling happens up the display hierarchy, but, if you listen /dispatch events on a custom dispatcher(singleton) or systemmanager or toplevel application, we can call it as a global event.